# ACF of MA(2) with constant

Tags: time-series, econometrics

Consider

$$Y_t =5+u_t-0.5u_{t-1}+0.25u_{t-2}$$

Because the regression has a constant (5) this is still valid?

$$\rho_1=(θ_1+θ_1θ_2)/(1+θ_1^2+θ_2^2)$$

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to know?

Comment: I wanna know if the ACF of lag 1 of this MA(2) with constant is the same of the ACF of lag 1 of a MA(2) without the constant(5).

Comment: $\text{Corr}(X,Y) = \text{Corr}(aX+b,cY+d)$... so you can shift by a constant, or multiply by one, or both, without changing the autocorrelation function.

Answer (score 4):

Constants are irrelevant for autocorrelations: $\rho_1$ is defined as $\gamma_1/\gamma_0$, where $\gamma_j$ is the autocovariance
$$
\gamma_j=E[(Y_t-\mu)(Y_{t-j}-\mu)]
$$
So any constants get mopped up in $\mu$.

In your example, we have that $\mu=5$, and hence,
\begin{align*}
\gamma_j&=E[(Y_t-\mu)(Y_{t-j}-\mu)]\\&=E[(u_t-0.5u_{t-1}+0.25u_{t-2})(u_{t-j}-0.5u_{t-j-1}+0.25u_{t-j-2})]
\end{align*}
But obviously, this would be the exact same calculation for *any* $\mu$.